# Anyone suggest why my code is creating an error in basic_ios and sstream?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, std, stringstream

I get the following errors which is a slight improvement after taking weeks (very part-time) getting the errors *out* of *my* code:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\sstream(451) : error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
1>        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\ios(151) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
1>        This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::basic_ostringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::basic_ostringstream(const std::basic_ostringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>        ]
```

I am migrating from the CLI to `std::` classes which I have even less experience with.

I think where it is saying "This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function" the function being referred to is my `std::ostringstream os;`.

I use `os` like as follows:

```
        os << "Level: " << levelName << ", contains unexpected header at line " << (numMatched + 1)
            << "\nExpected:\n" << longStringHeader;
        addToErrorSTDstring(os);
```

because `std::string` concatenation took a line up with each addition.

The only way I use `ostringstream` is

```
bool LevelParser::addToErrorSTDstring(std::ostringstream os){
```

which I believe ildjarn just perspicaciously identified as the problem for me.

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that you're trying to copy an instance of `std::ostringstream`, but all standard streams are *non-copyable* objects (in C++11 they are, however, *movable*).

That's the root of the problem<s>, but without seeing your actual code we can't give you concrete suggestions on how to fix it</s>.

---

**EDIT** (in response to OP's edit):

`addToErrorSTDstring` undoubtedly takes a `std::ostringstream` by value, i.e. has a signature like:

```
T addToErrorSTDstring(std::ostringstream os);
```

Instead, you need to pass it by reference, i.e. change the signature to something like:

```
T addToErrorSTDstring(std::ostringstream const& os);
```

or:

```
T addToErrorSTDstring(std::ostringstream& os);
```

(depending on how you use it).

If you're new to C++, then you need to stop what you're working on and brush up on language fundamentals such as references and const-correctness.

Comment: You fixed it! Not seen 'succeeded' on this project for a long time, thanks.